# creating Map from List is not giving expected result

Tags: java, list, hashmap, java-stream

I have the two list objects as shown below, from which i'm creating the map object.

```
List<Class1> list1;
List<Class2> list2;
HashMap<String,String> map = new HashMap<>();
for(Class1 one : list1){
 if(one.isStatus()){
   map.put(one.getID(),one.getName());
}
}

//iterating second list
for(Class2 two : list2){
 if(two.isPerformed()){
  map.put(two.getID(),two.getName());
}
}
```

The above code works fine ,  want the above to be written using streams.
Below is the sample code using streams().

```
 map = list1.stream().filter(one.isStatus()).collect(toMap(lst1 -> lst1.getID(), lst1.getName());
 map = list2.stream().filter(...);
```

But the "map" is not giving the expected result when written using stream() API.

Comment: You cannot re-assign like that. You have to update the map, or create another map that you add all of the elements to.

Comment: Use `map.putAll()`.

Comment: If you see the code posted, it is working with traditional foreach block, not wrking with stream()

Comment: There are three overloads of the `toMap()` method in the `Collectors` class.  The minimum static factory requires that you supply two function objects of type `Function`, the key mapper function and the value mapper function.  In the code you provided, I do not see two function objects.

Comment: What do you think happens when you write `map = list.stream()....collect()`? It re-assigns the map variable to a new map. What ever it was pointed at before, is left unmodified.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stream concatenation `Stream.concat` may be applied here to avoid `map.putAll`

```java
Map<String, String> map = Stream.concat(
    list1.stream()
         .filter(Class1::isStatus)
         .map(obj -> Arrays.asList(obj.getID(), obj.getName())),
    list2.stream()
         .filter(Class2::isPerformed)
         .map(obj -> Arrays.asList(obj.getID(), obj.getName()))
) // Stream<List<String>>
.collect(Collectors.toMap(
    arr -> arr.get(0), // key - ID
    arr -> arr.get(1),
    (v1, v2) -> v1     // keep the first value in case of possible conflicts
));
```

The code above uses a merge function `(v1, v2) -> v1` to handle possible conflicts when the same ID occurs several times in `list1` and/or `list2` to keep the first occurrence.

However, the following merge function allows joining all the occurrences into one string value `(v1, v2) -> String.join(", ", v1, v2)`.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what expected result you're not seeing but I created a minimal working example that you should be able to adapt for your own use case.

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Person> personList = new ArrayList<>();

        Map<Integer, String> personMap = personList.stream()
                                                   .filter(Person::isStatus)
                                                   .collect(Collectors.toMap(person -> person.id, person -> person.name));
    }

    private static class Person {
        public String name;
        public int id;


        public boolean isStatus() {
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: i want to iterate two different List and store the results coming from two different List in the map object as shown in the post above.

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
List<Class1> list1;
List<Class2> list2;

Map<String, String> map1 = list1.stream().filter(Class1::isStatus).collect(Collectors.toMap(Class1::getId, Class1::getName));
Map<String, String> map2 = list2.stream().filter(Class2::isPerformed).collect(Collectors.toMap(Class2::getId, Class2::getName));

map1.putAll(map2);
```